# Android JWPlayer conflicts with Play Services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jwplayer

I am trying to include JWPlayer in my project using Maven repo. The problem is the library conflicts with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1`

**Error message:**

```
All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.6.1, 8.3.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0

There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

I tried to exclude the library using the following lines but it didn't work

```
compile ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+') {
    exclude module('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0')
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

**build.gradle content:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.1'
    compile ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to read the [pom](https://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/jwplayer-android-sdk/2.5.3+164/jwplayer-android-sdk-2.5.3+164.pom) of jwplayer: there you can find the list of dependencies of your dependency. Then you can decide to exclude the modules:

```
compile ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+') {
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
}
```

or groups:

```
compile ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

or a module of a group:

```
compile ('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-android-sdk:+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
}
```

depending on your needs.

Comment: Nice with the pom advice, really helpful! The problem is the build is still failing with the another error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.6.1.` Any idea why?

Comment: I have posted build.gradle content